# Facebook Android SDK Log In failed with facebook.apk

Tags: android, facebook

I'm developing an android app that needs facebook log in. I'm using facebook SDK for android. The app works fine if there is no facebook for android installed in the phone, but can not  log in if it is installed, it just asks for cofirmation but do nothing after pressing OK.

Comment: is there is any error to show?

Comment: could you explain the problem bit clear? any logs or codes that will be helpful for us

Comment: Providing information (code snippets, error logs) helps.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Actually no error is shown in log cat or even in the app. After pressing log in in my app, a login page of facebook app appears for id and password.After giving id and password a dialog asking for confirmation appears ,pressing ok return to the login page of my app again.This only happen when the facebook for android app is installed otherwise after pressing the log in, a web page of facebook is shown for id and password and login succeeds after submitting. The same problem occurs for the sample codes given with the facebook SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is something wrong when catching the return information from the Facebook app.

Check your Activitys `onHandleIntent(Intent arg0)` or `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`